# Google ad-words API authentication issue

Tags: google-api, google-ads-api, google-api-java-client

I am trying to authenticate against adwords API using OAuth 2.0 for native application.

I've created MCC production account and MCC Test account. 
I've accepted Terms and Conditions and successfully submited my billing information in MCC production and test account.

I am following official tutorial and successfully generating refresh token. (https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/guides/authentication)

I am trying access my MCC TEST account, not trying connect to production one.
But unfortunately I am getting error when trying connect to AdWords from my Java code. 
First of all I was using my MCC TEST developer token and in this case I am getting:

```
 faultString: [QuotaCheckError.ACCOUNT_INACTIVE @ ; trigger:'&lt;null&gt;']
 faultActor: 
 faultNode: 
 faultDetail: 
    {https://adwords.google.com/api/adwords/cm/v201306}ApiExceptionFault:<message>[QuotaCheckError.ACCOUNT_INACTIVE @ ; trigger:'&lt;null&gt;']</message><ApplicationException.Type>ApiException</ApplicationException.Type><errors xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="QuotaCheckError"><fieldPath/><trigger>&lt;null&gt;</trigger><errorString>QuotaCheckError.ACCOUNT_INACTIVE</errorString><ApiError.Type>QuotaCheckError</ApiError.Type><reason>ACCOUNT_INACTIVE</reason></errors>
```

Next I was trying to switch to my production token but still pointing to MCC TEST account. Getting new error:

```
 faultString: [QuotaCheckError.INCOMPLETE_SIGNUP @ ; trigger:'&lt;null&gt;']
 faultActor: 
 faultNode: 
 faultDetail: 
    {https://adwords.google.com/api/adwords/cm/v201306}ApiExceptionFault:<message>[QuotaCheckError.INCOMPLETE_SIGNUP @ ; trigger:'&lt;null&gt;']</message><ApplicationException.Type>ApiException</ApplicationException.Type><errors xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="QuotaCheckError"><fieldPath/><trigger>&lt;null&gt;</trigger><errorString>QuotaCheckError.INCOMPLETE_SIGNUP</errorString><ApiError.Type>QuotaCheckError</ApiError.Type><reason>INCOMPLETE_SIGNUP</reason></errors>
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

If you receiving INCOMPLETE_SIGNUP errors, please read [error handling guide](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/common-errors#QuotaCheckError)